# Test Project in Visual Studio 2010 for a Windows Service Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing

I am working now in a Windows Service Project and I am having a lot of headaches trying to debug the service, I found a lot of article on how to debug a service but none of them worked for me :(
[How to: Debug Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

There is no way after attach the process to enter in my breakpoints (set breakpoints everywhere)

Then I found another creating a windows form inside the project but that Solution is kind of dirty (but a solution).[Testing a Windows Service From Within Visual Studio](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2010/02/testing-windows-service-from-within.html)

So the real question is, is there any possible way to create a test project to test the service? (I don't have experience with testing, but I know is a good practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to debug the service or code that service runs?

In the past I would create one project for a service, one project for a library that contains the logic, and one project for a console app that would be used to test and debug the logic locally. That setup covered most of the debugging needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I ended using this approach:
[**Debugging Windows Services under Visual Studio .NET**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10153/Debugging-Windows-Services-under-Visual-Studio-NET)
Is pretty much what everybody suggest to do, but in another way to do it. Thanks @AlexS